# React js: Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

im using react router v6 and i every time i use initializing for authentication in my main file it shows this error. i cant find a solution in the internet for it. i want to render some routes only when there is a user but now it doesnt render anything.

AuthNavigator

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import app from './firebase';
import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AuthStack from './stacks/AuthStack';
import AppStack from './stacks/AppStack';
import StaticStack from './stacks/StaticStack';

function AuthNavigator() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => app.auth().currentUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      if (initializing) {
        setInitializing(false);
      }
    });

    // cleanup subscription
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return 'Loading....';

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<StaticStack />} />
        <Route path="auth/*" element={<AuthStack user={user} />} />
        <Route path="app/*" element={<AppStack user={user} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default AuthNavigator;
```

App.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AuthNavigator from './AuthNavigator';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthNavigator />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I fixed it. The import of the Router was wrong. How ever yesterday i got error when using BrowserRouter

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue. My issue is because of the following reason.
I had a **Header** component which consists of **NavLink** which is a router component. I placed this **Header** component inside the **App** component. My **App** component was like this:

```
function App() {
  return(
      <Header/>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}/>
          <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  )
}
```

In the above App component, I have placed Header component outside of Router. Since in the **Header** component I have used **NavLink** which is a Router component caused this error. Then I moved **Header** component into the Router component then it worked fine. Finally my code looked like this:

```
function App() {
  return(
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}/>
          <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 30):

**Already wrapped in Router?**

if your component is already wrapped in a Router. Make sure you are importing `useLocation` from `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`. this worked for me.

Comment: I think its good idea to use eslint rule [`no-restricted-imports`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports) to prevent that problem in the future:
`name: "react-router"`, `importNames: ["useLocation"]`, `message: "Make sure you are importing useLocation from react-router-dom instead of react-router."`

Comment: @tito.300 Thank you speed 3 hours because my app use to work and som places I had used react-router. react-router-dom worked!!!

Answer (score 23):

Make sure that your App component in `index.js` is wrapped with `BrowserRouter` like this

```
const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: weirdly this fixes the issue,  even in a micro frontend architecture, where you don't use the index.js for the rendering..

Comment: Don't forget `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 10):

In case you run into this problem when running a test, don't forget to wrap your import of App in Router as well. My crude example is below.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { App } from '../App';

test('renders Box', () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  const boxElement = screen.getByLabelText('box-outline');
  expect(boxElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error coming up from inside a test. The component I was testing contained a `NavLink` component, and I wasn't rendering a `Router` in the test.
This error disappeared after wrapping my component in question with `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Simple solution 

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when using `{useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'`

```
function App() {
  const { pathname, hash, key } = useLocation();
  //function using pathname hash and key

  return(
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
        <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}/>
        <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

throws the same error even with the  in the correct place
I fixed it by explicitly wrapping the useLocation() within the router

```
function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Inner/>
    </Router>
  )
}
function Inner() {
  const { pathname, hash, key } = useLocation();
  //function using pathname hash and key

  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
      <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>}/>
      <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin/>}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Comment: Saved me big time. Thank you! Yours was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because Vite was bundling two copies of the same version of react-router-dom... check the outputted bundle for `* React Router DOM` and see how many copies there are.

If that's the case, the solution will differ. In my scenario I think it's because I was referencing other local npm packages using `file:`... once I switched to a npm workspace that fixed it.

Comment: Same for me. I created an NPM package, but my peer dependencies didn't include React-Router-Dom

Answer (score 1):

So i fixed like this structure

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

**App.js**

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

<Layout>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    {...}
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</Layout>
```

**Layout.js**

```
<Fragment>
  <Header></Header>
  <main className="container">{props.children}</main>
</Fragment>
```

**Header.js**

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

<header className={classes.header}>
<nav>
  <NavLink
    className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? classes.active : '')}
    to="/search"
  >
    Search
  </NavLink>
</nav>
</header>
```

**App.test.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

it('renders learn react link', async () => {
  render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>)
  const linkElement = await screen.findByText(/home/i)
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

im my case, the problem was putting BrowserRouter inside App.js file, solved it by moving this into index.js file and wrapping it around App.js

Former Index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} >
        <App/>
      </PersistGate>
    </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>
  
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Former App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation()
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/*' element={<LandingPage />} />           
          </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter> 
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

New Index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} >
        <BrowserRouter >
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>
  
);
reportWebVitals();
```

New App.js

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation()
  return (
    <div className='app'>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/*' element={<LandingPage />} />           
            <Route path='/registeration'  element={<Registration />} /> 
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Possible case description

Another very tricky case, where you can get this error, is **if you create your own,  separate npm library**, where you use `useLocation()`, `useNavigate()` or some other members of the `react-router` (or of the `react-router-dom` which just reexports many members of the `react-router`).

### Issue

If you export something from your library that is considered to be used inside of a `<Router>` of some application that uses your library, then those members of your own library most probably won't work. That's because the guard functions, located in source code of `useLocation()`, `useNavigate()` hooks (and not only there) will search for their own "library" instance of `<Router>`, not the one of the application.

### Solutions

#### Solution 1 (simple and tested)

I have used dependency injection. It works for sure. I have checked this. That's how it could look like, if you use a component from your library:

##### @your-project/library/src/components/NavigationElement.tsx

```tsx
import { NavigateFunction } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface NavigationElementProps {
  /** This should be `useNavigate` instance, provided by the client application */
  useNavigate: () => NavigateFunction;
}

function NavigationElement(props: NavigationElementProps) {
  const { useNavigate } = props;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => { navigate('some-path'); }}>
      Navigate to some path
    </button>
  );
}

export default NavigationElement;
```

##### @your-project/application/src/App.tsx

```tsx
import { NavigationElement } from "@your-project/library";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavigationElement useNavigate={useNavigate} />
      {/*                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - here we inject `useNavigate`
                          of the application itself, the right one */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="some-path" element={<div>You are at some path</div>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Solution 2 (the best, but not tested)

Use `peerDependencies` clause of the `package.json` of your library and put `react-router-dom` (or `react-router`) there. In this case the code of those dependencies won't be included in the build of your library and the copy of the dependency, used by the application, will be used.
This solution seems to be better than the first one from all perspectives, but I didn't test it (that's why I wrote it second). So please write in the comments if it doesn't work for you.

#### Solution 3 (not recommended, avoid it)

Reexport from your library all members of `react-router-dom`/`react-router`, required by the target application, and use in your application them instead. This solution I wouldn't recommend, because the size of your library will be bigger for sure.

Comment: I came across this problem yesterday and tested solution 2. I can confirm it does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I faced this error when I used the `HOC` and context provider and placed my `Routing` component as the `context.provider's` child, and export my Provider component by HOC like this:

```
class Provider extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          something: this.state.something
        }}
      >
        <Routing />
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default HOC(Provider)
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your App.js you have something like

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route }
```

You need to move `BrowserRouter as Router` to index.js instead to use `useLocation` and other hooks

index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
//...
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and solved this putting BrowserRouter into App.js file.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>,
)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a package locally, you can get into this issue because the package is using a separate copy of `react-router-dom`.

I solved by adding it as 'external' in the package's `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react-router-dom'],
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```