# hide Navbar if user inside dashboard using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, show-hide

I am creating my collage project and I want to hide the navbar if the user in `window.location.pathname === "/admin" || "/employee" || "/publisher"` basically if used in the admin dashboard or employee dashboard or publisher dashboard

this is how my Admin dashboard looks like when I login into `admin`

[image: screenshot admin dashboard]

My `Navbar.js` file looks like this:

```jsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Navbar.css'
import LoginRounded from '@mui/icons-material/LoginRounded'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';


const Navbar = () => {
  
  //Navbar active color change
  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [location]);


  return (
    <div >
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style={{ backgroundColor: "#063970" }}>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Evalue Content</Link>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === "/" ? "active" : ""}`} to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item"><Link className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === "/service" ? "active" : ""}`} to="/service">Service</Link></li>
              <li className="nav-item"><Link className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === "/contact" ? "active" : ""}`} to="/contact">contact us</Link></li>

            </ul>
            <Button component={Link} to="/Login" variant="contained" size="medium" startIcon={<LoginRounded />} sx={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }} >Login</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

if anyone knows how to achieve this please let me know

Comment: add `display:none` to the navbar if the condition is met. use a state to do this and change the state value based on condition

Comment: can you give example off code

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useLocation, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    <Router>
        {!["/admin", "/employee", "/publisher"].includes(location.pathname) && <Navbar/>}
        <Routes>
           <Route path="" element={<Homepage />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: The code in which place i put in the `App.js` under the navbar Route???

Comment: the code above should replace your  simple `<Navbar/>` where you render it, im guessing you have it in App.js

Comment: Yes i rendered in the App.js

Comment: i edited the code, is it working as supposed to?

Comment: hey after doing that My website did not work and Found an error on the console. `Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`

Comment: yes you need to import the Router eg: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'` thats how you use it

Comment: I  already import that

Comment: are you sure the navbar is in the router? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70094611/14548500](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70094611/14548500), I don't know how else to help you

Comment: This is condsandbox please check `[condesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-jackson-tzdz7m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: id don't know what's UserState but i think you shouldn't wrap Router in other elements, try putting UserState in index.js and wrap it <UserState><App/></UserState> and if you want to wrap something like the Router and ToastContainer add an empty <></> instead of a div

Comment: `UsereState` is the Context that wrap ***App.js***

Answer (score 0):

A good approach that you can take is using React Hook useState and assigning it a value of true.

```js
const [navBar, setNavBar] = useState(true);
```

and then create a button to handle when this is open and close whit

```
onClick={() => setNavBar(navBar => !navBar)}
```

button example

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => setNavBar(navBar => !navBar)}> <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path></svg></button>
```

Comment: I want to hide the navbar if a user is login and the pathname is `/admin` `/employee` `/publisher`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably cleanest to handle this sort of behaviour using the tools that are provided to you by React Router.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
    <Route path="employee" element={<Employee />} />
    <Route path="publisher" element={<Publisher />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard navbar />}>
    <Route path="other" element={<Other />} />
    {/* ... */}
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This would allow you to do the following in `dashboard.jsx`:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Dashboard({ navbar }) {
  return (
    <>
      {navbar && <Navbar />}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

Instead of one single `Dashboard` component that can be rendered with and without navbar, you could also just use two different components for the two different layouts.

`<Outlet />` will be filled with the element provided under the nested route. (`<Admin />`, `<Other />` etc.)

For a more details about nested routes checkout [the relevant section in the React Router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes).

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Check if the current page is the dashboard page
  
const isDashboardPage = router.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");

{!isDashboardPage && ( 
<nav>
//enter code here
</nav>
)}
```

Comment: I am using NextJs

Comment: You should add explanation.